# Creating an application extension using java

Tags: java, file, operating-system

I made an application in java which locks files and changes their extension as **.LOCKED**
what i am asking is :

> 1- how do i make the windows recognizes that extension to be opened by that application by default ( not asking for the manual way .. i need an automatic way like when the program gets installed )
>
> 2- how do i make the program handle the .LOCKED extension when it gets opened ( now it only works when you select the file from inside the application )

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-verbs

Comment: thanks i think this what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure if I understood all you need to do.
For the first question, tho, there is a simple way to solve that problem. You need to right click the file you want to open, and point to the app you choose to be opened with. I think windows will remember in the future your choice.

[image: preferences for open with]

For second and third questions you should be more explicit than that.

Comment: - what you mean by 'explicit' ?
1- i made an application that locks your files with a password when you use it you need to enter the program and give it the files that you want to lock then it will start working 
what i need is another way to do that which is not by opening the program itself ...

Comment: 2- i want to make the operating system recognizes the extension of the locked files by that application which is '.LOCKED' i dont want to make it manully (like when i give the application installer to somone it should automaticly register that extension to be automaticly opened by that program )

Comment: 3- ( when the second problem is fixed .. now it recognizes the extension to be opened by the program ) how i make the program start working on the file when the user double clicks on that file i'm sure there is a way to do it in java but i don't know how
4- Your answer is a manual way to make the extension opens by default .I want to make the installer package of the program do it manually .

Comment: 5- Exemple : i see that you have 7zip isntalled ... you see that option in the picture of 7zip when you hover over it some functions apear (like creat archive if it is non archived or decompress it if it is an archive ) you can also do that manually by going to the 7zip.exe program and open it and compress or decompress some selected files but with that option when you right click on a file you don't need that just when you double click on the extension .7zip the 7zip application will get a command to start working with that file ...

Comment: i want to do the same with my program (when the second problem is fixed ) when i right click on the .LOCKED extension i want the program to start working on that file

Please give me the code in java which i can do that ... 
i can't be more clear that that :)

Comment: This is possible; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-verbs